# Issuing Access Tokens with Passport in limited lifetime

Tags: laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

**Backend** : Laravel api.
**Frontend**: Angular.

After setting up the Passport package on Laravel i use the regular way to authenticate user then issue token this way :

```
 $newToken = $user->createToken('myapp')->accessToken;
```

this works fine but the problem is the token life time is 1 year as it considered [Personal Access Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#personal-access-tokens) and as documentation says :

> Personal access tokens are always long-lived. Their lifetime is not
>   modified when using the tokensExpireIn or refreshTokensExpireIn
>   methods.

my question is how can i issue token for my user inside my application with limited lifetime ?

on the other hand it seems its dangerous to expose **`client_secred`** and **`client_id`** so i cant call `oauth/token` from my angular app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it is not the best solution, but this is what i came up, many thanks to [eightyfive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52139344/485474) answer:

first add this protected method inside your authentication controller.

```
protected function oauthLogin(Request $request)    
{
    $client = DB::table('oauth_clients')
        ->where('password_client', true)
        ->first();    
    $request->request->add([
        "grant_type" => "password",
        "username" => $request->email,
        "password" => $request->password,
        "client_id" => $client->id,
        "client_secret" => $client->secret,
    ]);    
    $tokenRequest = $request->create(
        env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token',
        'post'
    );    
    $instance = Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);    
    return json_decode($instance->getContent());    
}
```

then call the method inside login method only after authenticating the user:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        try {
            // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if ($token = Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {

                $user = Auth::guard('web')->user();

                $roles = $user->roles()->get()->pluck('name');

                $accessToken = $this->oauthLogin($request)->access_token; // instead of $user->createToken('token')->accessToken,

                return response()->json([
                    'token' => $accessToken,
                    'roles' => $roles,
                    'email' => $request->input('email')
                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
    }
```

this way the issued token is limited to the time you set in **AuthServiceProvider.php** :

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
        Passport::routes();

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addHour(1));

        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addHour(1));

    }
```